# Solve $(P\lor Q)\land(P\lor\neg Q)\vdash P$ using basic logic properties

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Solve $(P\lor Q)\land(P\lor\neg Q)\vdash P$ using basic logic properties

I've had a lot of trouble solving this one problem, but it needs to be solved using the basic 10 rules as outlined in EJ Lemmons "Beginning Logic."

Sorry if I'm being too simple or not clear enough, im a beginner at logic, but these are the steps I attempted.

1. I assumed broke apart the conjunction and assumed ~P and tried to see if I could get a reductio.
2. I assumed P, Q, and ~Q and tried to create a scenario where I would have to use v-elimination after I didnt get anywhere with #1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's better to add what you have tried to your post.

Comment: Correct; unpack the conjunction and then apply Proof by Cases (Disjunction elimination).

Comment: Can you list the rules you have available? Not everyone has EJ Lemmons' book to look them up.

Comment: I have Modus Ponens, Modus Tolens, Conditional Proof, v-introduction, v-elimination, &-introduction, &elimination

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint for a derivation using natural deduction rules:

$(p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q) ⊢ p$

$1). (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q)- premise$

$2). (p ∨ q) - E∧ in 1$

$3). p - assumption$

$4). p - Repetition- rule -from- 3 -(close-assumption-3)$

$5). p ⇒ p - I⇒ in 3,4$

$6). q - assumption$

$7). (p ∨ ¬q) - E∧ in 1$

$8)....$

The objective is to eliminate the disjunction in step 2 to obtain $p$, we already derivate $p ⇒ p$ and we need $q ⇒ p$ and here is where it gets difficult. Under the assumption of step 6 $q$ we now have to eliminate the other disjunction $(p ∨ ¬q)$ in orther to get $p$ and that way we can conclude $q ⇒ p$.

If you need more help I can write the full derivation.